# Site not 100% responsive

Tags: css, responsive

I created a site for a client. It was 3 columns but she wanted only two, so I adjusted the code a little bit and made it 2 columns. The featured post area under the slider is my problem; the whole site, except that area, is responsive. Viewing on a laptop or desktop monitor, that area looks fine. View it on a tablet or mobile phone, it does not resize. Here is the [website](http://blueislandanimalenergy.com/).

The code I'm working with is in the `style.css` file and this is the code:

```
.featured-pages .holder .information {
    max-height: 100%
    max-width: 140%;
    width: 140%;
    height: auto;
}
.featured-pages .holder.last .information {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 140%;
    width: 140%;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 0%;
    margin-left: 60%;
}
```

Comment: Can you change all instances of `140%` to `100%` and try again.

Also, change the classes `holder third` to `holder half` if you only want two boxes. The css is there already.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I did what you suggested. But I forgot to mention I also want the featured boxes wider and centered as well. I guess my issue was I set them at 140% and that was perfect except it was not responsive. Right now as it is, it looks great on mobile phones.  Thank you.

Comment: As it is now, I managed to get the site working responsive on tablet and mobile, but the layout is all crunched to the left on desktop. I want both featured containers to spread out evenly from end to end under the slider. and resize on mobile devices. I managed to adjust the size and margins via css but then it breaks responsive sizing on mobile. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am happy to announce my issue is resolved. I simply found some code under the Grid section at the bottom of the css style sheet. I changed the 3rd row to 49%, mimicking the half row:  
`.row .single  { width: 100%; }
.row .half      { width: 49.9%; }
.row .third  { width: 49.9%; }`

Thank you all who helped!